# Prevent div overlapping in position:absolute div

Tags: jquery, html, css

By clicking a button we created a dynamic div using jquery .

```
$("#add-div").on('click',function(){

$(".new-div").after('<div class="new-div" style="z-index:1; position:absolute;" >message</div>');

 });
```

Currently what happen is  , in webpage a new-div is already there ,  when clicking on the add-div then other new-div is created . The problem is the all new-div's are over lapped.
 The message of one div is write over the message of other div .

How to solve this ?

I tried `margin-righ:auto; margin-left:auto ;`
 Here i cannot change position:absolute .Here `position:absolute` is a must one . So i am **searching for a solution without changing position:absolute**

> Update : Please see this jsfiddle :
>   https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/pmcqj50j/1/

Thank you .

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/pmcqj50j/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qqx1w1ef/4/

```
$("#add-div").on('click',function(){
      var last_element = $('body').find('.new-div:last');
      var position_top = last_element.offset().top + last_element.outerHeight() + 10;
      $(".new-div:last").after('<div class="new-div" style="z-index:1; position:absolute; top: '+position_top+'px;">message</div>');
});
```

I made it right now, and it uses last element, and suming it position top + height, and adding 10 more pixels.

So you get absolute position, and always new append at last element.

Edited jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pmcqj50j/5/

To stop overflow you could use following css (fiddle updated too):

```
.parent-div { max-width: 236px; width: 236px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: thank you . But here the when we add more div then the message is going out side the win

Comment: message is going outside the window in down position and it going out side of the image . Is it possible to stop this ?

Comment: Please help to solve this quetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232949/styling-close-and-resize-button-for-content-editable-div-in-css-and-adding-rsize

Answer (score 0):

> Dear Fwlix, try this

Over lapped because position :  absolute
but you want it..
so check this 

    `'https://jsfiddle.net/4sm9dfs4/'`

you have to set height for new element....

Comment: Please help to solve this quetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232949/styling-close-and-resize-button-for-content-editable-div-in-css-and-adding-rsize

Answer (score 0):

Please check this working [Demo - jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DineshV/pmcqj50j/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <input type="button" id="add-div" value="Add Div" />
  <br/><br/>
 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="bord">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/8b/8a/00/8b8a007ae01adf400e12b26f3b93fb3a.jpg">
  </div>
 <div class="parent-div">
   <div class="new-div">
       message
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
$("#add-div").on('click',function(){

$(".new-div").after('<div class="new-div">message</div>');

});
```

CSS

```
.parent-div{
  position: absolute;
    top: 7%;
    left: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 85%;
}
.bord{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: hi , please check the out put .When i click the add div the double the number of current number of div is coming .