# Styling close and resize button for content editable div in css and adding rsize functionality by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I write some code for making close & dragging option for a  content editable div using jQuery.

```
$( '.new-div').draggable({
  containment: "#bord",
  create: function() { 
    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
  } ,
  drag: function() { 
    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
  } ,
  start: function() { 
    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
  } ,
  stop: function() { 
    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
  }
});
$(document).on("click",".closeButton",function(){
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Please see this jsfiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/dwk6fs5w/ . This is working .

But when I write the code for remove text on the div by click function then that close button disappear. Please help to solve this. I have some more questions:

How can I set width of that div according to the txt in that div .

Please see this js fiidle https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/dwk6fs5w/5/

Then I write the code for resize the content in that div using jQuery. This code also working. but what I need is I need to make the font resize button near to the div as below picture.
Please see the below picture.

[image]

In the picture user can resize the font size by increasing the div width by scaling the div using that button placed on bottom right corner. Please help to achieve this.

So here I have two requirements:

1. Styling the close and resize button as er the picture
2. Add resize functionality for that div using the new resize button.

Thank you.

Comment: @Minal Chauhan Please help to solve this

Comment: Did my answer worked for you? If so, please mark it as correcto, if not give us feedback to help you to achieve this.

Comment: @JordiFlores yes . It is working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, you need something like this?

```js
$( '.new-div').draggable({
                                    containment: "#bord",
                                     create: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     } ,
                                    drag: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     } ,
                                    start: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     } ,
                                     stop: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     }
                                  });
         $(document).on("click",".closeButton",function(){

                                    $(this).closest('div').remove();
                                 });
                                 
         $(".new-div").on("click", function(){
                       
                    var uscontent= $(".new-div").text();
                    
                    if(uscontent.trim()==="message"){
                    $(".new-div").text('');
                     
                      } });  
                      
       $("#font-size").on("change",function(){
                     var v=$(this).val();
                      $('.new-div').css('font-size', v + 'px');
                     });
$('.resizeButton').draggable({
containment: '#bord',
drag: function() {
 $('.new-div').height($('.resizeButton').position().top + 17);
 $('.new-div').width($('.resizeButton').position().left + 17);
  $('.new-div').width($('.resizeButton').position().left + 17);
  
 $('.new-div').css({ 'font-size': ($('.new-div').height() / 2.3)});

  
}
})
```

```css
.new-div { 
    z-index: 1; position: absolute; width: auto; word-break: break-all; text-align: center; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 15px; border:2px solid black;}
.parent-div {  
    max-width: 236px; width: 236px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }

.closeButton
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:-10px;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url('http://cdn-sg1.pgimgs.com/images/pg/close-button.png') no-repeat center center;
}
.resizeButton
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url('http://img.freepik.com/free-icon/resize-button_318-99883.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
   Font-size:<input type="range" min="12" max="120" id="font-size" />
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="parent-div">
     <div class="new-div" contenteditable="true">
     message
    <a class="closeButton"><label  hidden>.</label></a>
  <a class="resizeButton"><label  hidden>x</label></a>
     </div>
        <div class="bord" style="z-index: -1;">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/8b/8a/00/8b8a007ae01adf400e12b26f3b93fb3a.jpg">
            
        </div>
        
     </div>
 </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Really thank you friend . It's working. But i have some doubts.

Comment: @Felix - What doubts? ASk and I'll try to help.

Comment: 1)Width of the div is need to same as the width of the text . Currently the text is message , but the border box is wider . I need to set this same as text . https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/jaboLc3u/1/

Comment: 2)Now also when we clicking the message close button and resize button disappear .

Comment: 3)div size need to be same as the text size inside the div .Currently div size is bigger . So when i resize , a big gap or unwanted space coming between text and border of the div (4) the resize button always need to set in right bottom of image . But here some time the resizie button coming in the middle bottom

Comment: 1) just remove `right:0` on `.new-div` css, you are making this div 100% by telling left:0, right:0

Comment: <div class="new-div" contenteditable="true">
     message
     <a class="closeButton"><label  hidden>.</label></a>
      <a class="resizeButton"><label  hidden>x</label></a>
     </div> replace this to avoid text disappear

Comment: please see this js fiddle friend .https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/jaboLc3u/1/  . For some reason i need to set tel left:30% .please see this (1)https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/jaboLc3u/2/

Comment: Please see this question friend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235790/set-size-content-editable-div-based-on-the-text-inside-this . you can answer there .

Comment: This is a great example and much appreciated even 4 years later.