# set size content editable div based on the text inside this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set the size of content editable div same as the text inside it

.Please see this js fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/jaboLc3u/7/

```
      $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     } ,
                                     stop: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     }
                                  });
         $(document).on("click",".closeButton",function(){

                                    $(this).closest('div').remove();
                                 });

         $(".new-div").on("click", function(){

                    var uscontent= $(".new-div").text();

                    if(uscontent.trim()==="message"){
                    $(".new-div").text('');

                      } });  

       $("#font-size").on("change",function(){
                     var v=$(this).val();
                      $('.new-div').css('font-size', v + 'px');
                     });
$('.resizeButton').draggable({
containment: '#bord',
drag: function() {
    $('.new-div').height($('.resizeButton').position().top + 17);
    $('.new-div').width($('.resizeButton').position().left + 17);
  $('.new-div').width($('.resizeButton').position().left + 17);

    $('.new-div').css({ 'font-size': ($('.new-div').height() / 2.3)});


}
})                     

.new-div { 
    z-index: 1; position: absolute; width: auto; word-break: break-all; text-align: center; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 15px; border:2px solid black;}
.parent-div {  
    max-width: 236px; width: 236px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }

.closeButton
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:-10px;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url('http://cdn-sg1.pgimgs.com/images/pg/close-button.png') no-repeat center center;
}
.resizeButton
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url('http://img.freepik.com/free-icon/resize-button_318-99883.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: resize;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
   Font-size:<input type="range" min="12" max="120" id="font-size" />
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="parent-div">
     <div class="new-div" contenteditable="true">
     message
    <a class="closeButton"><label  hidden>.</label></a>
  <a class="resizeButton"><label  hidden>x</label></a>
     </div>
        <div class="bord" style="z-index: -1;">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/8b/8a/00/8b8a007ae01adf400e12b26f3b93fb3a.jpg">

        </div>

     </div>
 </div>
```

Here first loading the size of content editable div and text inside is correct . But when i try to resize the div then there is a gap coming between the text and border of the div .

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1753533/329cefb018f213ecd9243f4cab9ab68a

Some time this problem is also coming http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1753603/d27436262d454bee88bf53ebfab2049a

I tried `display:inline-block;` but it is not working .

How to solve this ?

Comment: ok . I will add code  . Please remove negative vote .

Comment: @Felix check my fiddle, it will solve your font-size problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your font-size problem, this is trickier than it seems.

kudos for this library : http://thdoan.github.io/scalem/

```js
  

$( '.new-div').draggable({
                                    containment: "#bord",
                                     create: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     } ,
                                    drag: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     } ,
                                    start: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     } ,
                                     stop: function() { 
                                    $(".new-div").css("width",'auto');
                                     }
                                  });
         $(document).on("click",".closeButton",function(){

                                    $(this).closest('div').remove();
                                 });
                                 
        
                      
       $("#font-size").on("change",function(){
                     var v=$(this).val();
                               $('.new-div span').css('font-size', v + 'px');
                     });
$('.resizeButton').draggable({
containment: '#bord',
drag: function() {
 $('.new-div').height($('.resizeButton').position().top + 17);
 $('.new-div').width($('.resizeButton').position().left + 17);
  $('.new-div').width($('.resizeButton').position().left + 17);
   $('.new-div span').scalem();
 //$('.new-div').css({ 'font-size': ($('.new-div').height() / 2.3)});

  
}
});
```

```css
.new-div { 
    z-index: 1; position: absolute; width: auto; word-break: break-all; text-align: center; left: 30%;top: 15px; border:2px solid black;}
.parent-div {  
    max-width: 236px; width: 236px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }

.closeButton
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:-10px;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url('http://cdn-sg1.pgimgs.com/images/pg/close-button.png') no-repeat center center;
}
.resizeButton
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
    background:url('http://img.freepik.com/free-icon/resize-button_318-99883.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    cursor: resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://thdoan.github.io/scalem/javascripts/jquery.scalem.js"></script>


<div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="parent-div">
     <div class="new-div" contenteditable="true" >
       <span data-scale-ratio="1" data-scale-reference=".new-div">
     message
         </span>
     <a class="closeButton"></a>
     <a class="resizeButton"></a>
     </div>
        <div class="bord" style="z-index: -1;">
            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/8b/8a/00/8b8a007ae01adf400e12b26f3b93fb3a.jpg">
            
        </div>
        
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Felix what problem? Font-size is has responsive size to it's parent div element. Font-size of message is changing when you resize the box.

Comment: @Felix you want the editable text box work as photoshop text field? I'm a bit lost in what your needs are. I think this example will point you on the right direction

Comment: so check this: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable is that working as you expect?

Comment: hi, could you please help to solve this problem in https://jsfiddle.net/felixtm/jaboLc3u/20/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean padding of resizable div? 
https://jsfiddle.net/bimbonkens/2mpjkxad/

```
padding: 0;
```

Comment: Thank you . i check your jsfiddle. But the problem is still there .

Comment: Do you mean you want the inner div snapped to the top-left corner at all times? I really don't understand what gap you mean :D